# Improving a regression model in R

Tags: r, regression

I have currently taken a sample from [here](https://data.world/data-society/capital-bikeshare-2011-2012).  The regression model I have written is as follows.

```
Regression1<- lm(Total_Users~Season + Hour + Holiday + Day_of_Week + Working_Day + Weather_Type + Temperature + Temperature_Feels + Humidity + Windspeed, data=SampleBikeData)
```

This is a lot of explanatory variable and just from looking at them it is plain to see that they are probably accounting for the same event. To test this I used

```
vif(regression1)
```

And found the following:

```
Season=1.248678, Hour=1.128906, Holiday=1.114115, Day_of_Week=1.026463,  
Working_Day=1.089905, Weather_Type=1.264801, Temperature=49.081744,      
Temperature_Feels=49.389973, Humidity=1.440386, Wind_Speed=1.197410.
```

So I eliminated the `temperature_feels` variable and ran a new regression and check the vif again. This time all the values were below 1.5 so none could be removed.

Is this the best model for the data or is there another way of removing variables without affecting the efficiency of the model?

Comment: We try to avoid using terms such as "best" since this is very hard to determine, nonetheless your approach looks good. You could use some other procedure such as step or LASSO to do feature selection if that is the goal.

Comment: The goal is to be able to predict when the ``Total_Users`` is at its highest. This will be difficult with 9 variables to contend with.

Comment: Why is that difficult?

Comment: @snoram you are probably right.

Comment: @user2974951 *time consuming is more appropriate.

Comment: I don't really understand since the model is going to predict your values and there will be no effort required from your part. Anyway, you could progressively drop variables from the model which you think are not important and compare all the models with an ANOVA, to check if they are equivalent.

Comment: LASSO was already mentioned. I suggest looking into it. Don't follow advice mentioning stepwise removal of predictors or even stepwise regression. Such approach have severe statistical issues.

Comment: As mentioned before, selecting variables is not always neccessary if you are just interested in the prediction. To avoid overfitting use the bevore mentioned lasso or ridge regression or elastic net of which the other two are special cases. If you have enough data to split your data into traning and validation set, you can just check your model for overfit by crossvalidation.